# The remote server returned an error 403 forbidden using oData source to read from SharePoint 2019 on-premise

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, odata, sharepoint-2019

I have migrated SSIS packages from SQL Server 2012 to 2019 but once I open them in Visual Studio 2019 I could not get the Sharepoint List source component working. Online article suggests that I should use oData source. This package reads SharePoint 2019 lists and dumps data into SQL server.

I tried configuring oData but being first timer. I do not know the correct config.
SharePoint Server 2019, Visual Studio 2019, SQL server 2019

Basically, I need to replace SharePoint list source component with similar component to make the packages work again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there might be a problem when working with Resource Paths. Can you try and use collections and use query options to manipulate your data and see if it works?

You can refer to the following documentation:

- [Using the OData Source in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3220/using-the-odata-source-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. 

The root cause is something to do with the FBA configuration we have. If i create a web application and site collection with default setting oData connects and I can see the list of lists. But we have FBA configured to our site that does not work.